# whats the problem with this code?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, sqldatasource

**I HAVE EDITED THIS BUT THE SAME PROBLEM :**

```
Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Updated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles SqlDataSource1.Updated
    For Each myRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        'Find the checkbox
        Dim lab1 As Label = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("Label1"), Label)
        Dim lab4 As Label = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("Label4"), Label)
        Try
            Using conn = New SqlConnection(constr)
                Using cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
                    conn.Open()
                    Dim sql As String = "UPDATE a1_ticket SET Travels = @travels WHERE travelid = @travelid"
                    cmd.CommandText = sql
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@travels", lab4.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@travelid", lab1.Text)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Next
End Sub
```

**ERROR :** OBJECT REFERENCE IS NOT SET TO THE INSTANCE OF AN OBJECT

Comment: What line do do you get the exception exactly? Most likely one of your label variables - lab1 and/or lab2 are null. Use the debugger, put break points and check for yourself.

Comment: Can you point out the line of error. Is it when you cast labels?

Comment: When you've fixed the NullReferenceException, the next port of call is going to be the SQL injection attack vulnerability... use parameterized queries instead of concatenating values into your SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Error is in this line : `Dim strSql As String = "UPDATE a1_ticket SET Travels = '" & lab4.Text  & "' WHERE travelid =" & lab1.Text`

```
travelid is Text so it should be travelid='" & lab4.Text & "'".
```

Comment: How do you know the type of travelid? It could be an integer field. The bigger problem with the SQL is that it isn't parameterized... but even so, I don't think that's the cause of the reported error. The exception would talk about invalid SQL or something like that, not a NullReferenceException.

Comment: @Jon Because lab4.Text is string, so it would be string or need to typecast in integer or something else.

Comment: No, because it's *building* a string - a SQL statement. Sure, the current code isn't performing any validation that `lab4.Text` is *actually* a valid integer, but if it is (and if `travelid` is an integer field) then it's a valid SQL statement. There's no reason to assume that quotes are the solution here.

Comment: @Jon, you are right. I was assuming that field as string because of assigning the string on that.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect that this is going to be the culprit:

```
Dim lab1 As Label = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("Label1"), Label)
Dim lab4 As Label = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("Label4"), Label)
```

`FindControl` returns null/Nothing if it can't find a control with that ID. My guess is that because you've got potentially multiple rows, the IDs of the controls within each row are autogenerated with extra information. I suggest you look at the HTML on the page and see what's being generated... you may want to look at finding a better way of finding an individual control within a row.

As mentioned in comments, you should then parameterize your SQL statements to avoid SQL injection attacks.